# How to remap Tab key to two dots/period key presses

Tags: autohotkey

I want to map two dot/period key presses to Tab key in AutoHotkey script. I tried to map similarly as its shown for [remapping semicolon key - on AutoHotkey forums](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/33122-how-to-remap-semicolon-key/), but it doesn't work. I tried following:

```
1. `..`::Tab
2. ..::Tab
```

AutoHotkey gives an error

[image: AutoHotkey script error with period key remapping] .

I tried searching on [AutoHotkey Remap docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#Remap), but couldn't figure it out. The period key is the one with the greater than mark and not the number keypad period key. See this: [Dot/period key](https://qphs.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-a73f11cbc1c9d6bafea7ac968b79f7ab)

Addition info/context in response to reply by user 0x464e:

Basically, I am trying to expand Emmet style abbreviations in devtools style sub-panel since the [chrome devtools team wont implement it](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=360242).

I am not a fast typist, so it's a pain to type complete property names. For example, if I want to type `margin-top`, (see the image), Chrome autocomplete brings up margin, margin-block margin-block-end etc.

[image]

Now, for margin-top, you need to at least type `margin-t` to get the autocomplete to show that property.

This is the case for many very common CSS properties like margins, paddings, etc., so autocomplete isn't great.

On the other hand, if I just type `mt` and have Autohotkey expand to `margin-top`, it's much much faster, saves me much time and keeps me sane.

Basically, I have setup some hotstring in .ahk script and they work too.

[image: ahk-css-emmet-style-hostrings]

However, if I press `mt` followed by a Tab key press, Chrome's autocomplete takes over and hotstring fails, (try once to see the problem). Instead, currently I press spacebar, or . (period) to trigger the hotstring. It works, but the problem is it leaves a space or a dot with the expanded text. [see this].

[image: expanded css property-name via ahk hotstring]

So, that's the actual reason I wanted a double period key trigger to replace Tab.

It would be great if the hotstring trigger would work with a double period key, but doesn't leave the trigger character itself and then have send Tab so as to jump to the value input of the just expanded property.

Answer (score 1):

You're not really looking for a traditional remap, which is why you didn't find it from the documentation.
Remapping is just simply remapping one key to another, but you're not trying to do that. You're trying to make some action do another action.

Anyway, what you're asking is doable, but there's loads of different ways it can be achieved with difficulties varying from simple to extremely advanced & complicated.
You'll need to specify things more clearly before this can be answered properly.
Biggest questions that pop into my head right away are at least:

- Should this work everywhere, or just in text input fields?
- How should the original functionality of <kbd>.</kbd> be preserved, if at all.
  (What should happen after the initial <kbd>.</kbd> keypress?)
- Should there be some timeout between the keypresses?
- Etc, this is just what I could think of right away, but surely there's more.

---

Anyway, for now I can give a simple implementation with a [hotstring](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm):

```
:*?:..::{Tab}
```

So this is a hotstring with the `*` and `?` [options](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#Options).
I'm guessing these would probably be pretty good options for this.
So what this does, is it presses backspace twice and sends a `Tab` if you type `..`.
This should be fine for text editors, but it leaves much to be desired (the points I listed above aren't considered since I can't know what you're looking for. This is just what a default simple hotstring can offer).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've updated my question to provide the actual context/use case  of my question. If you any need additional info, I'll try to provide it too. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you don't actually want the additional mapping of `..` to <kbd>Tab</kbd>, but instead just want to update your existing hotstrings to activate immediately (without waiting for an [EndChar](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#EndChars)) when the hotstring is followed by `..`

Normally, you might look to the [Ending Characters](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#EndChars) option to create this functionality, but since you want multiple characters to trigger this, we need to look to other options.

---

I will be using the example of `::mt::margin-top` for my sample implementation. Extend any changes I make to these to the rest of your hotstrings in the script you screenshotted.

Here are the changes I am making to this example:

1. Add your `..` to the end of each of your hotstrings triggers. For example `::mt::margin-top` becomes `::mt..::margin-top`. However, at this present, this still requires some sort of ending character to be pressed in order to proc. Let's fix that in the next step
2. Add the [Asterisk Modifier](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#Asterisk) to the hotstring. From the docs:

> * (asterisk): An ending character (e.g. Space, ., or Enter) is not required to trigger the hotstring.

---

#### Final code for `::mt::margin-top` example:

```
:*:mt..::margin-top
```

And extend this `*` insertion and `..` appendation to each of your hotstrings.

Hope this helped! Lmk if you need any more help or changes.